# USB BulkTransfer Read Data Available

Tags: android, usb

Is it possbibe to find out how many bytes are avaialable in the FIFO buffer using the Android USB Host API's (controlTransfer, bulkTransfer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 2 Bytes are reserved for Status Registers. Everything after is user data.